How do I fix an error on the MainActivity, the R.id.nav keeps saying a constant expression is required?
I keep getting an error on while trying to create an App.
// Determine which fragment to display based on the item selected
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_insert_meal:
            selectedFragment = new InsertMealFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_view_meals:
            selectedFragment = new ViewMealsFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_delete_meals:
            selectedFragment = new DeleteMealsFragment();
            break;
        default:
            selectedFragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
    }>

The R.id.nav keeps saying a constant expression is required.
it is preventing me from running the App. Please help, how can I fix this?
I have tried all the ways to fix it and I am not sure how to correct this.

   binding.bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when (item.itemId) {
                R.id.fragment1 -> {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.lock_selected)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.yourFragment)
                    binding.bottomNavigation.menu.findItem(R.id.yourFragment).isChecked = true
                    binding.bottomNavigation.itemIconTintList = null

                }

                R.id.fragment2 -> {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.selfie_selected)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.yourFragment)
                    binding.bottomNavigation.menu.findItem(R.id.yourFragment).isChecked = true
           

                R.id.fragment3 -> {
                    navController.navigate(R.id.privateBrowserFragment)
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.yourFragment)
                   
                    binding.bottomNavigation.menu.findItem(R.id.yourmenuid).setIcon(R.drawable.selfie)
                    binding.bottomNavigation.itemIconTintList = null
                }

                R.id.homeFragment -> {
                    item.setIcon(R.drawable.home_selected)
                    navController.navigate(R.id.homeFragment)
                    binding.bottomNavigation.menu.findItem(R.id.yourFragment).isChecked = true
                   binding.bottomNavigation.itemIconTintList = null
                }
            }
            true
        }

        binding.bottomNavigation.selectedItemId = R.id.homeFragment

if you are using bottomNavigation them this would be helpful for you you can convert this code to java easily by using chatgpt
